# Standard code of my firm for php index sites. Good code?

Tags: php, optimization

So I'm wondering if the code (see below) is what could be called "good php code". Its used where i work and i am trying to come up with a better solution to write this template.

The $requestedPage variable is used twice, first in the if and after that in the switch statement i don't know why but i think there should be a better possibility.

The content is loaded through the require_once statement which will load the page content surrounded by the head.php and foot.php that contains the html - template.

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    require_once 'lib/rb.php';

    require_once 'head.php';


    $requestedPage = $_POST['page'];

    if(isset($requestedPage)) {
        switch ($requestedPage) {
            case 'list':
                require_once 'page/list.php';
                break;
            default:
                require_once 'page/home.php';
                break;
        }
    } else {
        require_once 'page/home.php';
    }

    require_once 'foot.php';
?>
```

Comment: No, that's not good code. For starters, using $_POST variables essentially as page URLs is bizarre.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Maybe could you try to explain how i could improve the method of finding the requested page? I would really appreciate it because I'd really like to improve the code.

Comment: Also `filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` is essentially a null operation. It does not modify $_POST in place. You need to assign the result somewhere. `$_POST = filter_var_array(...` is what you meant.

Comment: Well, traditionally you'd get to a page via a URL, not a form POST, so you should be probably be using a $_GET parameter instead. I'd look into a PHP microframework like [breeze](https://github.com/whatthejeff/breeze), though, as big `switch` statements showing various pages went out of style in the late 90s with PHP-Nuke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the checking done twice. If the parameter is not set, it automatically goes into the **default** case of your switch statement.

So, your code can be

```
$requestedPage = $_POST['page'];
switch ($requestedPage) {
        case 'list':
            require_once 'page/list.php';
            break;
        default:
            require_once 'page/home.php';
            break;
}
require_once 'foot.php';
```

**Edit**: As @mario suggested in the comments, suppressing E_NOTICE which is shown when executing `$requestedPage = $_POST['page'];` can prove problematic in future, when there is a relevant notice and you have suppressed it. So, you should either suppress notices **ONLY** in production code, or check if `$_POST['page']` is set before accessing its value, in the statement

`$requestedPage = $_POST['page'];`

Comment: Adding to this, the `if(isset())` should check `$_POST['page']`, you first line here might trigger a Notice.

Comment: Actually the user's code 
`$requestedPage = $_POST['page'];` already triggers a notice when the parameter is left empty. So I assumed he was dealing with it.

Comment: Yes, if anything the `isset` should occur on the $_POST array. But suppressing the notice (okay, that's just my opinion) is inadvisable, as it's highly useful debugging and **logging** information.